# Title of blog in email alerts for blog portlet in liferay

Tags: email, liferay, blogs, title, portlet

In **liferay** the **email alerts** on new blog creation in blog portlet doesn't have the **Blog's title**, in configuration where the template is shown there is a list of **predefined variables** but none for Blog Title. 
How can i modify the template to get the dynamic Blog title, or we can do this in **Hook** or might there be some other way.
& I am using liferay 6.2 CE
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the response [here](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/56390603). Looks like this is included in Liferay 7( I have not verified it myself). If you are using a version prior to liferay 7 then follow the advice in the link